# Loop through users folders and delete a folder

Tags: linux, centos6

How can I loop through the `/home` directory for each user and delete a folder? It will be a common one called `/home/$user/.quarentine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get the list of users
USERS=`ls -l /home|grep "^d"|awk '{print $NF}'`
#Loop for each user and delete the files
for i in $USERS
do
  rm -rf /home/$i/.quarentine
done
```

Comment: it is not a good idea to parse the output of ls (see the link in the other answer). Better use a simple loop, like thirafael did.

Answer (score 1):

In a single line:

```
for user in $(ls /home); do rm -Rf /home/${user}/.quarentine; done
```

Comment: better say `for user in /home/*`. [It is not good to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)